# spotify doesn't care about mission control settings

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control, spotify

I have my Mission Control (el capitan, 10.11) settings the way I like:
"When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application" is OFF.

This works very well except for Spotify. Also, I have Spotify "locked" for a specific Desktop.

It's very annoying to do a cmd-tab and switch 3 desktops. And then, it doesn't switch back with another cmd-tab.

How can I make Spotify obey the Mission Control setting?

Comment: To clarify, I just don't want to switch to Spotify when I'm on another desktop. This is ok for every other application.

Comment: I am not clear as to what you are describing as the problem.

Comment: Spotify doesn't behave as the other windows. If I'm on desktop 1 and Spotify is on desktop3, when switching to Spotify (with cmd-tab), I don't want to go to desktop3.

Answer (score 2):

Spotify doesn't support multiple windows. The reason for this statement is absence of New Window in File Menu. So it switches to the desktop it is at.